# Interactive Maps in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm curious if I can do following this in wp7.

I want to do some basic things in park like:

- Pan, zoom,
- display POI layer.
- Route from current location to park attractions,
- concession stands,
- misting stations,
- bathrooms, etc.
- Display additional info.
- like height requirments and thrill levels when tapping on a ride
  location.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think pan is not possible available. you have to set the zoom level explicitly or via the map's zoom button. There are a few Bing Maps API you can tap on for POI data. you should look at the following services

Route Service - Allows you to calculate location from one point to another http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966826.aspx

Search Service - Allows you to do location searches eg. find nearby restaurants, petrol stations etc.

Other useful services

Geocode Service - Allows you to resolve address using coordinates and vice versa

Imagery Service - Gives you access to image data to build maps